# How to validate url which is used to register resource using rest api?

Tags: validation, rest, url

How to validate url which is used to register resource using REST API?

For example:

```
REST API POST http://xyz.wt.com:7001/rd?endpoint=node1&domain=D&EXTRA=qsjoiusswq2
```

In this I need to validate that the URL contains info only about endpoint and domain, `EXTRA` is useless, and how to find is there any extra info end user is passing?

Answer (score 0):

For most programming languages there are libraries to parse URLs.

For Python, you could use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```python
import urllib

url = "http://xyz.wt.com:7001/rd?endpoint=node1&domain=D&EXTRA=qsjoiusswq2"
result = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)    
query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(result.query)
print(query)
keys = set(urllib.parse.parse_qs(result.query).keys())
print(keys):
print(keys == {"domain", "endpoint"}
```

Output:

```
{'endpoint': ['node1'], 'EXTRA': ['qsjoiusswq2'], 'domain': ['D']}
{'EXTRA', 'domain', 'endpoint'}
False
```

So you keys in the query are *not* what you expect.